# Is there any way to convert .log file generated from BUS master (CAN tool) to .asc file (Vector support) with out bus master?

Tags: can-bus, python-can

I am trying to make a script which convert BUS master .log files into .asc files without bus master. The files are just column adjustment but I am stuck with different time format used in the files' format.

Example: 11:29:26:2229 (.log) = 41366.222900 (.asc)

Please help me out to understand the .asc file time format.

Answer (score 1):

In the header of the .asc file, the start time and date is given in the very first line. E.g.:

```
date Mon Okt 24 10:01:03 2022
```

The timestamps of the individual CAN messages (and other events) are just offsets to the start time in seconds. I.e. given the header above, the timestamp

```
123.456
```

Would be 123 seconds and 456 milliseconds after 10:01:03, which is 10:03:06.456

---

Details about the .asc format can be found in the `Doc` folder in CANoe's installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

.asc time format =  hour * 3600 + min * 60 + sec.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).